# Morse functions on 4-manifolds

Tags: geometric-topology, morse-theory, 4-manifolds

What are examples of 4-manifolds that have more Morse critical points than topologically required? For example, $\pi_1(M), H_*(M; \mathbb{Z})$ have less than $k$ generators but any Morse function on $M$ has more than $k$ critical points.

**Edit**
PVAL-inactive explains in the comments that in dimension 4, it is a big open problem whether simply-connected manifolds admit perfect Morse functions and so now looking at non-simply-connected manifold looks more promising.

Also, what are some 4-manifolds $M$ such that the unit disk tangent bundle $DTM$  requires fewer critical points than $M$? A related question: what are some 4-manifolds $M,N$ that are not diffeomorphic but the unit disk tangent bundles $DTM, DTN$ are diffeomorphic?

Maybe there are examples of some of theses things in dimension 3?

Answer (score 3):

It's a well known open question whether every smooth closed simply-connected smooth 4-manifold admits a so-called perfect Morse function (a Morse function with only critical points of even index), so you are unlikely to find a compact simply-connected examples in your first question.

In the non-compact case, examples are pretty plentiful. First of all, there are plenty of contractible 4-manifolds which are not simply-connected at infinity. Many of these are so-called Mazur manifolds, which are the result of attaching a 2-handle to a winding number one knot in the boundary of $S^1 \times D^3$ (so these contractible manifolds admit Morse functions with two critical points).

There are also exotic examples. Due to a theorem of Taylor, any large exotic $\Bbb R^4$ (a manifold homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^4$ which does not smoothly embed in $\Bbb R^4$ has infinitely many index 3 critical points for any proper Morse function. As any contractible and simply-connected at infinity $n$-manifold for $n \ne 4$ is diffeomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$, the disk bundles of such exotic 4-manifolds will give examples to your second question (there should be loads of compact examples as well but not necessarily with differing Morse numbers).

Comment: Are there examples of closed manifolds M (without boundary) such that DTM admits a Morse function with fewer critical points than any Morse function on M? Not necessarily in dimension 4?

Comment: @user39598 I don't know of any such example. DTM has a natural Morse function which looks very similar to a Morse function on M (the same number of crit. points of each index and I THINK the same alg intersection #'s between ascending and descending spheres) by adding a Morse function of M to the square of a Riemannian metric on the fiber.

Comment: In higher dimensions the conditions for being able to form cancellations and such are completely algebraic topological, so if you could reduce the number of critical points for a Morse function on DTM it seems highly plausible that you could perform the same elementary moves on M to reduce the critical points there as well. In dimensions 5 and lower you need more than the algebraic intersection number to do cancellations, and I don't know what happens there.

Comment: Right. There is a natural morse function on DTM built using the morse function on M and they have the same number of critical points. So the morse number on DTM is at most the morse number of M. I am wondering if the morse number on DTM is ever strictly smaller than the Morse number on M.

Comment: @user39598 My point was that in high dimensions additions and cancellations on DTM probably directly translate to additions and cancellations on M, though I'm not near a proof. By Cerf theory, we can get between any two Morse functions on a manifold by a sequence of elementary moves which involve adding in cancelling pairs, handle-slides and cancellation, and it is hard to imagine such a sequence for DTM not immediately translating to a sequence for M (at least in dimensions where cancellation is entirely controlled by the alg. intersection number).

Comment: This is why my original question was about dimension 4.